# Angular-cli и LESS

Tags: angular2, less, angular-cli

Всех приветствую, я использую Angular 2 и Angular-CLI, я хочу для каждого своего компонента писать стили на LESS, но понятия не имею как это сделать, я установил 
npm install less --save и не знаю в каком файле что написать, чтобы LESS файл компилировался в css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проверь настройки файла **.angular-cli.json**, если в `defaults` установлено `"styleExt": "scss"`, то при генерации комонента cli автоматически будет создавать `*.scss` файл и компилиться это все будет при билде приложения. Если же там стоит `css`, то используй команду `ng set defaults.styleExt scss`
вот чтиво https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-css-preprocessors